# Trying to make use of httpCache android?

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I am trying to use okhttpclient with retrofit to setup caching... How do I setup the expiration and add it to my restApiManager? Not sure what service is suppose to be...

Here is the code:

```
public class ApiManager {

    private static final String API_URL = "ip";


    public static AsynchronousApi getInstance() {
        if(service == null) {
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            File cacheDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            HttpResponseCache cache = null;
            try {
                cache = new HttpResponseCache(cacheDir, 1024);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            okHttpClient.setResponseCache(cache);

            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(API_URL)
                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                    .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
                    .setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {

                        @Override
                        public Throwable handleError(RetrofitError arg0) {
                            if(arg0.getResponse().getStatus() == 404)
                                return new Exception("Url does not exists");

                            return new Exception(arg0.getMessage());
                        }
                    })
                    .build();
            service = restAdapter.create(AsynchronousApi.class);
        }

        return service;
    }



//    //create adapter
    private static final AsynchronousApi ASYNCHRONOUS_API = getInstance();

    //call service to initiate
    public static AsynchronousApi getAsyncApi() {
        return ASYNCHRONOUS_API;
    }

    //Call interface
    public interface AsynchronousApi {

        //USER

        //Register User
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/register")
        public void registerUser(
                @Field("email") String email,
                @Field("username") String username,
                @Field("password") String password,
                Callback<UserResponse> callback); //


         //Search User
        @GET("/search_user")
        public void searchUser(
                @Query("username") String username,
                Callback<UserResponse> callback); // userfound  cache users
```

Comment: Which version of retrofit and okhttp are you using?

Comment: I am assuming you asked this before you answered, but yes I am using the square up version

Comment: Just make sure you are using latest retrofit and okhttp latest jars. as I recall its 1.4.1 and 1.51

Comment: Read my comment under your answer that is not true, it does not auto-cache...

Answer (score 4):

You are using the com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient but you should rather use retrofit.client.OKClient which takes OkHttpClient as a parameter. Also if okhttp jar is already in your path you dont need to use this code at all. Only perhaps if you are facing trouble with cache availability.

```
 private static RestAdapter REST_ADAPTER = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(API_URL)
        .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
        .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
        .build();
```

Comment: oh ok, and by the okhttp jar in my path do you mean the retrofit version? and what do you mean by, I do not have to use it at all - like it will auto cache because it sees okhttp there?

Comment: Yes it will auto cache just make sure you have retrofit and okhttp in your path. But remember only Get requests are cached.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, so I do not need to setup the whole cache method then if I understand you correct, as long as I have both okhttp and retrofit as libs?

Comment: Yes! No doubt about it.

Comment: Why were you calling it in your question then, by the way? I do want to implement it to be safe on the availability, please see the new method 2, maybe you can see what I need to replace service with or if I am using it properly now...

Comment: There are good reasons to create the client, your code dosent depicts it. So just suggested that auto caching happens. The code I posted is now removed and I dont use it anymore. Auto caching did the trick for me. Your code seems good to me now. For cache expiration use @Header(cache-control: *****) this is a retrofit provided annotation and can be used on each method.

Comment: I am having an issue though with the service ... not sure what service is suppose to be? Also, auto-caching how much size does that allow up to?

Comment: Also, can you see if you can help answer this question of mine, thanks a lot btw appreciate the help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425993/how-to-retrieve-cookies-in-android-retrofit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244968/retrofit-auth-cookie?rq=1 This answers your question I guess.

Comment: I tried to use that answer, but was having a hard time implementing the setHeader part...

Comment: So this is not true... it does not auto-cache... I finally got my request up an running, and it constantly requests the text... the images I have cached with picasso... but I have to figure out how to cache the text still, and just adding headers to retrofit does not do it

Comment: As I would say, if you havent configured retrofit it will auto cache. Cache Control headers wont work if server dosent allow to cache. Also, Only GET request can be cached. If you can write junit tests please write a performance test requesting multiple times you will see the difference. You can also make to requests one with cache control other one without it. Also see max-stale attribute of cache control